# Public key size for different elliptic curves

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, key-size, ecies

Let's say I want a certain level of security (eg 128 bits) when using ECIES but I also want to minimise communication, does the elliptic curve used matter on the size of the public key? If it does matter, what is the current state of the art elliptic curve and how does it compare with popular elliptic curves such as Curve25519 or secp256k1?

Comment: [Did you do any research?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/80601/what-is-the-key-length-of-shared-secret-by-curve-25519-ecdh) Curve25519 has 32 bytes for ECDH, and  secp256k1 has 33-bytes for compressed...

Comment: @kelalaka: for ECIES, you don't need the y coordinate, and so it'd be 32 bytes for either...

Comment: @poncho yes, exactly, since there is no need for the $y$ coordinate for the ECDH. 33-byte is the standard Bitcoin public key size.

Comment: @kelalaka Yes I know that curve25519 uses a 32-byte key but I was wondering if there's any curve that does better?  I just read [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/59573/information-theoretical-lower-limit-on-the-size-of-public-and-private-keys) and was wondering if any curve does better. As far as I can understand this is not possible but I am not an expert and I couldn't find anyone stating this (probably it's obvious) that's why I am searching here.

Comment: What do you mean by doing better? Generic attack on the Dlog reduces the security to 128-bit for Curve25619. Do you want a lower security margin? Set up your security level and multiply it by two, the look for such a safe curve on safetycurves. Why 32-byte is large for you? Compared to RSA this is cheap to store.

Comment: I should have clarified, doing better in terms of key sizes. I know that this is a big improvement compared to RSA but I am doing an application where I am trying to minimise memory as much as possible while still keeping the same security level.

Comment: Use https://www.keylength.com/en/compare/ to decide what you need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If it does matter, what is the current state of the art elliptic curve and how does it compare with popular elliptic curves such as Curve25519 or secp256k1?

Well, if you have an elliptic curve with a large subgroup of size $q$ (which is prime), then we know how to compute a discrete log within that subgroup in $O(\sqrt{q})$ time, and this applies to all elliptic curves (actually, all groups).

So, to make this attack take $2^{128}$ time, we need a $q \approx 2^{256}$.

And, because of the Hasse theorem, for a prime curve of characteristic $p$, we have $p + 2\sqrt{p} > q$, or in other words, the smallest $p$ can be is about 256 bits.

The standard way to represent a public key is to give the $x$ coordinate as an integer; this is a value between 0 and $p-1$; that is, a 256 bit value.

Hence, selecting a curve other than Curve25519, secp256k1 or P256 doesn't buy us anything; either that alternative curve would have reduced security or have a public key that's as least as large.

About the only thing you can try to come up with a reduced method of transmitting the $x$ coordinate; one simple-minded approach would be to always select an $x$ coordinate with $k$ bits of 0 at the top (and just not transmit those $k$ bits explicitly); finding such a key using rejection sampling would take $O(2^k)$ time and would save $k$ bits - perhaps doable if you need to save a byte or two - obviously infeasible to save more than that.  I don't know of a cleverer approach to find public keys that meet a similar space saving technique.