# How to find the encoding of an RSA public key?

Tags: rsa, encoding

What practical methods is there to reconstruct an RSA public key in unknown format?

As an illustration, in a database I find this (which doesn't look like ASN to me):

`0x0602000000A40000525341310004000001000100170D33754DB739E6298F70465182848A72C980F7D15D45E3EC91448AFC6088FCED3A880A7CAD8EEF053064F6932183A29A102D3A390E99ECDE03B4456AD5B0389CB3213160511EE2B5473F887294A7572F12A351A70D9DC7C155DFA3C9763986299AE555CFE166123FC2A904199D6A3B0C6AD3F519A849CF4397D91085B30EE6`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The first step is to check how much data we have. That gives an idea of the size of the public modulus: although it is possible to [compress an RSA public modulus](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1692/555) $N$ to less bits than its bitlength $\lceil\log_2(N-1)\rceil$, this is uncommon; and most RSA public key formats are larger than the public modulus, and only much larger for digital certificates. Here, excluding the `0x` prefix (meaning hexadecimal in many computer languages), the given is 276-character uppercase hex; that probably is hex, coding 138 bytes or 1104 bits, which suggests a 1024-bit RSA public key (the next lowest common size, and also one of the lowest common size).

Next is to confirm this; guess the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness); and locate the public modulus $N$. The data coding $N$ typically is visually random-like (here, pointing towards the end of the data blob). As a quick test we can use that the low-order bit is set; and the hypothesized bitlength (if exact, which is typical) gives us another bit set. When we have an hypothesis on the location and coding of $N$, we can check it with an often-sufficiently-selective test: the public modulus is a [composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_number) with no factor quickly found. With a factoring program that finds factors less than $b$, odds that an incorrect odd guess pass this test are less than
$$\epsilon(b)=\prod_{p\text{ prime, }2<p<b}{p-1\over p}$$
That's residual odds below 5.1% to wrongly conclude that a guessed encoding is correct if we only check for at-most-32-bit factors, and perhaps less than a percent for the program I use, [gmp-ecm](http://ecm.gforge.inria.fr/) <sub><sup>(todo: justify)</sup></sub>; this is often good enough (especially if we have several examples).

Our data seems to use little-endian byte ordering, transformed to hex using big-endian ordering of the two characters of each hex byte. With that convention, the last 256 characters "170D3375..85B30EE6" would be a 1024-bit (128-byte) public modulus of 0xE60EB385..75330D17, which passes the above test. No other simple ordering that I checked does.

Immediately before that is "01000100", which by the same convention decodes to 0x00010001 and would be the common public exponent $e=65537=2^{(2^4)}+1=F_4$ (the fourth [Fermat number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number)).

Immediately before that is "00040000", which by the same convention decodes to 0x00000400, and that would be 1024, the conjectured bit length of the modulus (with $e$ always on 32 bits, as in early Windows CryptoAPI, explaining why there is no length for $e$).

The "52534131" immediately before matches "RSA1" in ASCII, and that could be a format indicator.

Searching for that string, it comes that Microsoft used that as a [`magic` number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) for RSA keys, followed by `bitlen` and `pubexp` on 32-bit (strongly reinforcing the credibility of the above three educated guesses) in a [`RSAPUBKEY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387685(v=vs.85).aspx):

> ```
> typedef struct _RSAPUBKEY {
>   DWORD magic;
>   DWORD bitlen;
>   DWORD pubexp;
> } RSAPUBKEY;
> ```

[contributed by CodesInChaos]: The first 8 bytes are a [`PUBLICKEYSTRUC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387453.aspx):

> ```
> typedef struct _PUBLICKEYSTRUC {
>   BYTE   bType;    // 0x06 = PUBLICKEYBLOB -- The key is a public key.
>   BYTE   bVersion; // 0x02
>   WORD   reserved; // 0x0000
>   ALG_ID aiKeyAlg; // 0x0000a400 = CALG_RSA_KEYX -- RSA public key exchange algorithm. 
> } BLOBHEADER, PUBLICKEYSTRUC;
> ```

[contributed by Maarten Bodewes]: The overall structure is a [`PUBLICKEYBLOB`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375601(v=vs.85).aspx#pub_BLOB):

> ```
> PUBLICKEYSTRUC  publickeystruc;
> RSAPUBKEY       rsapubkey;
> BYTE            modulus[rsapubkey.bitlen/8];
> ```

Note: The above formula for the size of the `modulus` field can only be valid if `bitlen` is a multiple of 8; and then it is prudent and customary to use only multiples of 64, or even 128 for good measure.

Comment: Just checked the format, it's precisely as described. Note that the magic should always be "RSA1" in ASCII, but that Microsoft shows it as a number (i.e., because it is interpreted as little endian, it is in reverse). The magic is therefore in the order you expect. I hate little endian, in case you didn't notice yet.